# Is there a way to prevent DataFrame from inferring schema and force it to use the schema given?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a JSON DataFrame in the following way:

```
val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(jsonRDD)
```

and I was wondering if there is a way to force `jsonRDD` to be read by using only `schema` and stop it from inferring on it's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being something totally irrelevant as I was inputting wrong dataset.